# List index out of range, Indexing with sort( key=lambda)

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, text-files

so I am reading from a file that I want to sort by the cy and cx elements. The text file I am reading from looks something like this.

```
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="2150" cy="750" fill="#abae3b" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="2950" cy="1350" fill="#e1e25b" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="2250" cy="2250" fill="#babd44" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="550" cy="1750" fill="#5a610d" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="950" cy="1550" fill="#70761a" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="650" cy="1950" fill="#606610" style="fill: rgb(195, 252, 241);"></circle>
<circle r="36" class="dot" cx="1350" cy="1050" fill="#858a26" style="fill: rgb(0, 82, 72);"></circle>
```

The python code is trying to read from the text file, and sort it based on the value at cy, then the value at cx.

```
data=[]
with open(r"SomeSpaceInMemory.txt","r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        data.append(line)

data.sort(key=lambda n: (n.split()[4],n.split()[3]))
```

When running this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    data.sort(key=lambda n: (n.split()[4],n.split()[3]))
  File "file.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    data.sort(key=lambda n: (n.split()[4],n.split()[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When the line is split it should look something like this so I don't know why the index is out of range.

```
['<circle', 'r="36"', 'class="dot"', 'cx="450"', 'cy="1850"', 'fill="#555c0a"', 'style="fill:', 
'rgb(0,', '82,', '72);"></circle>']
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: 1. you most likely have an empty line in the end of the file 2. looks like you should be using an html parser such as beautiful soup

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it.  Why do you have r"..." around the name of the file?  It's not a regular expression.  And I agree with @DeepSpace

Comment: Also, not the question you asked, but you could simplify your code with: `data = datefile.readlines()`

Comment: @FrankYellin the `r` [prefix signifies a raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), not a regular expression

Comment: @DeepSpace.  Eek.  Thanks.  The only time I ever see them used is why regular expressions, and I was confusing this with a different language.  Still unnecessary.